# What do initial conditions for a PDE mean in Fourier space?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Suppose I have some function $f(t,x)$ which obeys some second-order PDE. Suppose further that the initial conditions
$$
f(0,x) = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \partial_t f(0,x) =0
$$
are satisfied.

What do the initial conditions mean in Fourier space? That is to say, if I consider the transform $F(\omega,x)$ where
$$
f(t, x) \ = \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega\ e^{- 2 \pi i \omega t} F(\omega,x) \ .
$$
It seems that the initial conditions imply
$$
0 \ = \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega\ F(\omega,x)
$$
as well as
$$
0 \ = \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega\ ( - 2 \pi i ) \omega F(\omega,x) \ .
$$
This seems to me like all this tells me is that the function $F(\omega,x)$ must be odd - can anything else be inferred from the initial conditions in Fourier space?

Comment: It doesn't have to be odd. Consider $F(\omega,x)=e^{-\omega^2/2}[A(\omega^3-3\omega)+B(\omega^2-1)]$ for nonzero $A,B$. Then both integrals vanish but $F$ does not have definite parity.

Comment: @Semiclassical Good point. So basically we learn nothing from the Initial conditions.